# Improving a configurable list with a lot of comboboxes

Tags: usability, interface, apple

[image]

I did some testing with the interface that looks a lot like the Apple Mail Rules dialog, and received the following feedback from users:

- Way too many click actions
- Unclear what a rule does
- Bad maintainability

The above feedback seem to mostly apply to long rules with a lot of added options or just a lot of rules in general. User with a few short and simple rules didn't seem to have a problem with the interface.

What would be a good way to reduce the complexity of the dialog if the user adds a lot of comboboxes

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Basically:

I have the same interface as Apple Mail Rules, but i received some negative feedback. How can i improve it.

Comment: That's not really an answerable question. it's more like you're asking us to do your UX work for you. We're not a free consultancy service; we're here to help build a repository of useful, reusable UX questions and answers.

Comment: Yet there are a lot of similar questions where users ask for help in improving a design that aren't on hold.

I edited the question in a more general question.

Comment: Good edit-the question is less design review and focuses on the core problem: multi-conditional filtering. Related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45486/web-based-sql-query-builder

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting rid of the + button for every row. Instead make the rows draggable.

Further in the "Perform the following actions" section, the controls are not abiding with the whitespace convention set in the prior section. See if you can adjust the controls in the second row so that they don't stand out.

Another way to look at it is if you see all your rules are filtering based on the name of the senders. The first 2 rows in the first section is same throughout. If this is the case for you then i would recommend something like a tag setup for the names

Something in the lines of http://codepen.io/warcops/pen/MYpzLW